# an alternative to all and any from python to Java?

Tags: java

I'm tryin' to code how to find out a determinant in a matrix with Java 8. There are some particular cases for that work. For instance, when a matrix is an upper triangular. I coded this work with Python 3.6 using this code:

```
def is_upper_triangular(a, order):
    for i in range(1, order):
        if all(a[i][j] == 0 for j in range(order)):
            return True
    return False
```

This is very easy and clean code, so I've thought to code with Java, but I don't find any "all" method with Java to use it. I've found some information about that in this web page with negative solution. Is there any alternative to solve my problem.
Here's my java code for now:

```
public static double detMatrix(double[][] matriz) {
        if(matriz.length == 1)
            return matriz[0][0];
        if(matriz.length == 2)
            return matriz[0][0] * matriz[1][1] - matriz[1][0] * matriz[0][1];
        double det = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++){
            double[][] nm = new double[matriz.length-1][matriz.length-1];
            for(int j=0; j<matriz.length; j++){
                if(j != i){
                    for(int k=1; k<matriz.length; k++){
                    int indice = -1;
                    if(j<i)
                    indice = j;
                    else if(j>i)
                    indice = j - 1;
                    nm[indice][k-1] = matriz[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                det += matriz[i][0] * detMatrix(nm);
            else
                det -= matriz[i][0] * detMatrix(nm);
        }
        return det;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Both the python and java solutions will have quadratic time complexity. You could using an `ArrayList<Boolean> bool` for your truth counts and then do `Collections.count(bool, true);`

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking for a specific keyword feature in Java, but different programming languages afford different approaches.

For example, instead of an `all` operator, why not simply use `Arrays.fill(...)`?  The python that looks like

```
 for i in range(1, order):
     if all(a[i][j] == 0 for j in range(order))
```

would look like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length, i++) {
     Arrays.fill(a[i], i+1, a[i].length, 0);
 }
```

Likewise, the `any` operation in Python might look like it is doing more with less, but really it collapses down to

```
 for (Element element : allElements() {
     if (element satisifies condition) {
         ... statements ...
     }
 }
```

With Java, the above loop can work, but it makes the inefficiency apparent.  If you really don't like to see what your code is doing, you can hide this in a method.

```
 public List<int> findFives(int[][] a) {
      ...
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this could be done by streams, but the idea behind a stream is to process elements individually.  In this case the value is dependent upon the position within the 2d array, so any stream processing will have to collapse each element into a triplet of (value, x, y) and that's a lot of memory overhead.

Comment: I don't want to fill o replace numbers in a matrix, i want to find out all the zeros in a pre-defined matrix

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems java works with Streams, but Streams is a hard option beause, it seems, it converts any matrix in an Array 1D, and this is very difficult when i want to search all 0's under main diagonal matrix. I suppose some people know to solve it but i don't know about that. 
Other problem with that is we have to load some java packages. So i've found another solution without to load extra java packages. Here is:

```
public static double [][] transMatrix(double [][] mat) {
        double[][] matrizT = new double[mat[0].length][mat.length];
        for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j<mat[i].length; j++)
                matrizT[j][i] = mat[i][j];

        return matrizT;
    }
    public static boolean isUpper(double[][] mat) {
        int p = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<mat.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(mat[i][j]!=0)
                    p = 1; break;
            }
        }
        return p == 0;
    }
    public static double productDiag(double[][] mat) {
        double prod;
        prod = 1.;
        for(int i=0;i<mat.length;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<mat[0].length;j++)
                if(i==j)
                    prod *= mat[i][j];

        return prod;
    }
    public static double detMatrix(double[][] matrix) {
        if(matrix.length == 1)
            return matrix[0][0];
        if(matrix.length == 2)
            return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[1][0] * matrix[0][1];
        if(isUpper(matrix) || isUpper(transMatrix(matrix))
           || (isUpper(matrix) && isUpper(transMatrix(matrix)))){
            return productDiag(matrix);
        }
        double det = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
            double[][] minor = new double[matrix.length-1][matrix.length-1];
            for(int j=0; j<matrix.length; j++){
                if(j != i){
                    for(int k=1; k<matrix.length; k++){
                    int index = -1;
                    if(j<i)
                    index = j;
                    else if(j>i)
                    index = j - 1;
                    minor[index][k-1] = matrix[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                det += matrix[i][0] * detMatrix(minor);
            else
                det -= matrix[i][0] * detMatrix(minor);
        }
        return det;
    }
```

Thanks everybody for your help.